# The multi-part identifier "table1.id" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

when I run following SQL query:

```
update table1 set table1.last_update_time= GETDATE(), table1.last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER 
from table1 join inserted on table1.id = inserted.id;
```

on my MS SQL Server db, I am getting the error:
'The multi-part identifier "table1.id" could not be bound.'

Here is requested DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE
table1
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    type CHAR(1),
    katastr CHAR(25),
    currency CHAR(3),
    last_update_time DATETIME2 DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    last_updated_by CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'suser_sname()' NOT NULL,
    rowid INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT table1_p PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT f1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table2 (id)
);
```

Please help, any kind of help is very appreciated.

Best regards,
mismas

Comment: Can you share with us the DDL of the table `table1`? What columns and datatypes are used?

Comment: Your update statement sets the value of column `last_updated_by` but the table has a column `last_update_by`. This is however not the reason for your error. I think you have simplified the question so the real reason is nowhere to be seen any more. The DDL is also wrong. You need parenthesis around `id` in the primary key constraint.

Comment: @Mikael, you are right, I simplified table DDL (changed column names, table name and removed columns for which I thought that are not relevant), but the query is the same (of course, with respect to changed names). So this errors in DDL and naming is just consequence of my typing. This query is the part of the trigger I am trying to create on my table. Eventually I decided that I will not needed it, so I removed it. When I saw your answers, I tried adding it again, and now it mysteriously worked ... I didn't change anything else in the SQL except add that statement again... :)

Comment: Maybe it was some typo afterall, I did not see :D, tnx anyway for your time and comments.

Comment: I edited the question and corrected mentioned errors/typos.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a alias, like:

```
update tb set tb.last_update_time= GETDATE(), tb.last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER 
from table1 as tb join inserted on tb.id = inserted.id;
```